# Implement CPU extensions in a kernel module

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, kernel, kernel-module, kernel-extension

I'm looking for information relating to implementing certain CPU extensions in a kernel module. I've found something related: http://www.mirrors.docunext.com/lxr/http/source/arch/mips/kernel/unaligned.c in fact, it's the only source code that I can find that is even close.

Basically, I have a binary only shared object built with certain CPU extensions, which I need to run on a slightly older CPU which has most of the instruction set, but not the fancy new stuff. Yeah, I know it'll be rather slow, but it's better than crashing with SIGILLs.

Comment: I think your question might be a little overbroad.  You already have the basic idea - intercept the trap that eventually results in SIGILL, and instead examine the user process state and emulate the instruction it tried to execute.  (I don't think you'll be able to do it from a module though - it'll probably have to be compiled in, unless you add some shims for the module to hook in to).  So what's the real question?

Comment: I was hoping that someone had experience with doing things like this, or at least point me in the right direction if I'm missing something. There's fragments in the kernel itself relating to FP chip emulation, as well as the link above. Writing the shim/framework seems like the next step for maximum reuseability/extensibility. Basically, I'm searching the source for SIGILL, and going from there. Is there something more efficient? Or, does someone know where a good place is for the trapping, i.e. file x line y? Sorry for lots of questions, I didn't want to start too many new threads.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, after reading the kernel source, it seems like there is already minor support for this. I really can't see how much it's actually used, but there exists a linked list to store the various emulated instructions. If I'm able to actually get this going, I'll probably change it to the kernel-header supplied tree.

If I'm understanding kernel modules right, there doesn't look like there would be an issue to support pluggable emulation.

Answer (score 2):

I think you can do this in userland. Install a handler for `SIGILL` with `sigaction()` and specify `SA_SIGINFO`. The field `si_code` in the `siginfo_t` allows distinguishing between several causes of `SIGILL`. For example, trying to emulate an instruction when the signal came from `kill()` does not make sense. The third argument to the handler points to a structure containing the CPU context at the time of the fault (see documentation). You can likely modify this and return from the signal handler, the changes taking effect; if that does not work, try `setcontext()`.

Obviously, it will be a bit less efficient than doing it in the kernel, but cleaner and safer.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this, but its slightly painful. The invalid opcodes need to be intercepted, so you either need to modify the existing illegal instruction handler, or wrap the handler, which is dirty and complicated.

If you want to avoid any kernel mods, but do as a pure kernel, the wrapped-exception approach is probably the only way to do it. If you can modify the kernel, the patched handler is better.

Answer (score 1):

i don't think you can fix this problem using a kernel module.  i think you either need to run this in a VM which allows the missing instructions (I would try using XEN)  or recompile the object so that it doesn't use them.

Comment: I think @joe means something like the old FP emulation tricks used on old processors without FP units.  I'm not sure ANYONE is doing research on this now.

Comment: The external FP unit is actually the 2nd part of the larger picture. But I'll mess with that when I come to it. Here's an x86 example (the target CPU is ARM): if the CPU did not have support for SSE2, when it encountered a ADDPD instruction, the kernel would throw (or something else like a filter, whichever is faster) an internal SIGILL to be caught by itself (kernel module, or etc.), which would then call the specific function that implemented ADDPD. It doesn't necessarily have to be a kernel module, it could be that the kernel framework for this would have to be written, which is fine.